# Using <paper-shadow> makes sibling elements unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

When I use `<paper-shadow>` in in my app, it blocks any user interaction with the contents of the element it is included within (its siblings) as it renders lots of stuff on top of it.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeshuamaxey/rL2pX/3/) demonstrates my problem with a hacked together element. [The docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/material.html#shadow-effect) mention something about using an extra wrapper, but this is in reference to the overflow property of the element. In any case, I was unable to solve my problem with wrappers.

Comment: This question has been editted with an updated link to a working JSFiddle

Comment: If you set `z-index: -1;` on `.paper-shadow` it fixes it... but that isn't an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This commit](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-shadow/commit/24d0c3bc4ff52f3868cd937e7d9f27a5376f6392) introduces  `{z-index: -1; pointer-events: none}`  to `.paper-shadow` which fixes my problem, but it is reverted in [the following commit](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-shadow/commit/c1d9ae99598787d4bd68712c0580dd79a6ddce46) with no explanation. [Later on](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-shadow/commit/6319c14df471a0839db8472e43e4265613b89e30) `{pointer-events: none;}` is re-added in response to [this issue](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-shadow/issues/6) which fixes my problem.

I've run bower update and there was no change to my local copy of paper-shadow. I can only conclude that the bower isn't pulling the latest version of the GitHub repo.

Comment: Run `bower cache clean` to make sure you pull the latest from the Github repo